# Angular 6 filter JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

Hi I am having trouble filtering some JSON. My console.log in my component does not show anything. I would think it would display [2]

JSON file

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SearchFlService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getLabels = (searchValue: string) => {
    const fl = searchValue.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();

    return this.http.get('/assets/data/fl/' + fl + '.json')
      .pipe(
        filter((items) => items === 2),
        map(
          response => {
            return response;
          },
          error => error)
      );
  }
}
```

component

```
this._searchFlService.getLabels(data.value.searchPlant)
        .subscribe(items => {
          console.log(items);
        });
```

Comment: And what are you getting from it? Nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering the observable stream not the items array.

```
    return this.http.get('/assets/data/fl/' + fl + '.json').pipe(
      map(items => {
        return items.filter(items => items === 2);
      }, error => error)
    );
```

*the above assumes that the get request returns the array [].

Comment: ahh. that makes sense. It works. thanks. Though I do get this message
[ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: I solved it by adding this "Array<number>"
(res: Array<number>) => res.filter((item => item === 2),

Comment: Can we put an OR (||) condition here like (items => items === 2 || items === 5) ?